# how to write a urllib response to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write my response to a file, but I am not able to since its in bytes. Is there a way?

I tried adding utf-8 or ascii

```
import urllib.request

domain = input('Please enter domain: ')

url = 'https://api.somesite.com/v2/domain/'+ domain
token = '3fe6465b84f94cexxx'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, {'X-RFToken': token})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

for line in res:
    d = open("domainlist.txt", mode="wt")
    d.write(line)
```

Error:

```
Please enter domain: site.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thnh/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/URL request test.py", line 13, in <module>
    d.write(line)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file in binary mode instead:

```
with open("domainlist.txt", mode="wb") as d:
    d.write(res.read())
```

Comment: something so simple Thank you @blhsing